# Change Document Root For Heroku PHP Application

Tags: php, heroku, yii2

I'm creating a Yii 2 application and trying it on Heroku

The document root should be the web/ folder of that application

This is what I've tried:

- Create a Procfile in the root of that application

```
web:    sh www/config/web-boot.sh
```

- Create web-boot.sh in config folder

```
    echo "Include /app/www/config/httpd/*.conf" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
    touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
    touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
    tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
    tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext
    export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/app/www
    echo "Launching apache"
    exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
```

- From the config folder, I create "httpd" folder, and "default.conf" inside that folder

```
DocumentRoot "/app/www/web"
<Directory "/app/www/web">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and when I deploy the app, I get this error:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When I check the logs :

```
2014-07-12T20:23:08.476411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-12T20:23:06.313554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh www/config/web-boot.sh`
2014-07-12T20:23:08.465571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2014-07-12T20:23:10.025168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=richy-rich.herokuapp.com request_id=e4bb1124-5f2d-4a27-8df4-6fff9bc166b2 fwd="50.19.158.232" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-12T20:41:49.308914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=richy-rich.herokuapp.com request_id=5785ac83-c4fb-473e-b794-50ce491512c9 fwd="223.255.224.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

How to fix this ?
I don't understands that Procfile at all, thanks

**UPDATE**

Now I tried another solution,  I add this package to my composer.json

```
heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

And changed the Procfile into:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx web/
```

This time I got this error:

```
2014-07-12T21:12:58.960392+00:00 app[web.1]: This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php' command.
2014-07-12T21:13:00.147518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-12T21:12:58.044158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/`
2014-07-12T21:13:00.136787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-12T21:13:08.648874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=richy-rich.herokuapp.com request_id=a3bcc52d-2a7c-45ac-b21d-f856154d7e38 fwd="223.255.224.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Seems like this is because of my PHP version, since the version installed by heroku is 5.5.10, so I tried updating the composer php version into ">=5.5.11",
but I got another error (Man, This is 4.39 AM and I haven't sleep yet because of all these errors)

```
Problem 1
           - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
         Problem 2
           - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
         Problem 3
           - Installation request for cebe/markdown 0.9.x-dev -> satisfiable by cebe/markdown[0.9.x-dev].
           - cebe/markdown 0.9.x-dev requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
         Problem 4
           - Installation request for ezyang/htmlpurifier v4.6.0 -> satisfiable by ezyang/htmlpurifier[v4.6.0].
           - ezyang/htmlpurifier v4.6.0 requires php >=5.2 -> no matching package found.
         Problem 5
           - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer 5.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[5.2.x-dev].
           - swiftmailer/swiftmailer 5.2.x-dev requires php >=5.2.4 -> no matching package found.
         Problem 6
           - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer dev-master -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[dev-master].
           - swiftmailer/swiftmailer dev-master requires php >=5.2.4 -> no matching package found.
         Problem 7
           - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0-beta -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0-beta].
           - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0-beta requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
         Problem 8
           - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0-beta requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
           - yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer 2.0.0-beta requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0-beta].
           - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer 2.0.0-beta -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer[2.0.0-beta].
```

please kindy help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not using the official buildpack, but some sort of third party one (check `heroku config` and look for a `BUILDPACK_URL`).

Sort it out with the maintainer, or better, use Heroku's official PHP support (`heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL` and push a change). Then your `Procfile` will work (but you need to remove the `heroku/heroku-buildpack-php` dependency in `composer.json`, or move it to `require-dev`).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, 
I've read that it's installed by default in heroku so I don't need to install that.
but still cannot run the Procfile due to installed php version in heroku

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote. You're apparently not running the regular buildpack. If you run `heroku config` in your app, what is the value of `BUILDPACK_URL`?

Comment: The official buildpack comes with PHP 5.5.11-5.5.14, so it'll never say "This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php' command." on boot, and it will reject pushes with `heroku/heroku-buildpack-php` as a non-dev dependency. You're almost certainly running a third-party buildpack with a different PHP version and different behavior. You cannot use the official buildpack's boot command there, because it's all different.